# c# Custom library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, libraries

I am creating a custom library for sending emails.
Idea is to use `System.Net.Mail` or `Microsoft.SharePoint`.
Code will be executed in enviroment that has `System.Net.Mail` but not necessarily `Microsoft.SharePoint`.

Sharepoint library will be used only if Sharepoint address is set in configuration file.

The question is how to use `Microsoft.SharePoint` library without crashing program if whole library doesnt exist in a executed enviroment?

I do not want to add `Microsoft.SharePoint` library because it is against Microsoft rules.

```
 If(Enviroment.Libraries.Contains(Microsoft.Sharepoint)
    Use Microsoft.Sharepoint
 Else 
    Use System.Net.Mail
```

:)

This is the problem:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried

```
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\Web Server Extensions\\14.0", false))
        {
            if (regKey != null)
            {
                string installStatus = System.Convert.ToString(regKey.GetValue("SharePoint"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(installStatus) && installStatus.Equals("Installed", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Installed");
                }
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("NOT Installed");
        }
```

I can see (using regedit) that `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\SharePoint` is there but that code just does not see it :(

Comment: You'd be better of shipping the sharepoint DLL as part of your assembly. I think this nuget package might contain what you want https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/

Comment: Which source line causes the exception? The solution will be: Check the SharePoint assembly is available with Assembly.Load(), and _only_ conditionally execute any statement, variable declaration etc which uses types defined in that assembly

Comment: thank you both. i will try and respond later if any of that worked for me

Comment: That usually happens when you don't set `Copy to local` to true for the referenced file. So whatever you ship might be missing the file.